# CoordinatorLayout and align button relative to BottomSheet

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to create `Button` which will move together with `BottomSheet`. It should be positioned above `BottomSheet` parent. So I used `CoordinatorLayout` to achieve this. But if I anchor this `Button` above `BottomSheet` layout, its bottom half is cut off (I want to position it above `BottomSheet` layout like in `RelativeLayout`). Also if BottomSheet is hidden, its overlapping TabBar. Also Button is for some reason not following BottomSheet. I thought `CoordinatorLayout` would solve this issue. I dont wanna hand animate `Button` movement based on `BottomSheet` peek.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/but_location"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_medium"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomSheetContainer"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="end|top"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_location_icon"
            style="@style/button.shadow" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
                layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_above="@id/tabBar" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/tabBar"
                layout="@layout/tab_bar_layout"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="66dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

UI:

[image]

Comment: Can you share what UI you want to design?

Comment: Its like google map with bottom sheet where is some info. Location button should be above it and it should move together with bottom sheet behaviour (like sliding it, collapsing it etc) Bottomsheet is standalone component which can be used anywhere in my project, so it doesnt know if there is some view above or below it.